# Realm, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.realm.GroupRealmProxy

Tags: java

When I use the Realm, I come across with an error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.realm.GroupRealmProxy` the class Group is a subclass of RealmObject.
Hope some one to solve my question as soon as possible.

Comment: When you use which Realm ?  In what execution environment ?  When you use the Realm how ?  Didn't you get a stacktrace that you can post here ?  Where did "the class Group" suddenly come from ?  Where did the class "RealmObject" suddenly come from ?  And in fact, your reference to "my question" is actually void because THERE EVEN ISN'T ANY QUESTION AT ALL.

Answer (score 0):

[From Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found. The searched-for class
>   definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled,
>   but the definition can no longer be found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but the class that can't be found is generated by
Realm lib,exactly,the class is for the Moudle class.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry,it's too late to tell askers that the reason of the question can be solved by use Android5.0+ platforms.